# can't setcookie after session_destroy and cookie expire

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

After I destroy session on logout and `setcookie` to past so I can expire it, on next authentication I cannot set cookie again. Here is my logout:

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['id_user']);
session_destroy();
setcookie('logat', '', time() - 3600);
header("location: index.php");
```

and here is where I `setcookie` on authentication:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
session_start();
include('engine/core/dbconfig.php');
$password   = $_POST['password'];
$email      = $_POST['email'];
$hash       = hash('sha512', $password);
$hash_email = hash('sha512', $email);

$stmtt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users where Email=:email and Password= :hashed");
$stmtt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmtt->bindParam(':hashed', $hash);
$stmtt->execute();
if ($row = $stmtt->fetch()) {

    setcookie('logat', $hash_email, time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000));

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("Update Users SET Cookie_Log=:cookie_log where ID_User=:id_user");
    $stmt->bindParam(':id_user', $row['ID_User']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':cookie_log', $_COOKIE['logat']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("Update Cos SET ID_User=:id_user where cookie=:cookie_cos");
    $stmt->bindParam(':id_user', $row['ID_User']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':cookie_cos', $_COOKIE['cos']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $_SESSION['id_user'] = $row['ID_User'];
    $arr                 = array(
        'tip' => 'user',
        'id' => '' . $_SESSION['id_user'] . ''
    );

}
?>
```

i did a test and it seems the cookie is set but it's not inserted into the database. At first login it is inserted but after logout and relog the column `Cookie_Log` is updated to empty

Comment: `-3600` assumes that the user's clock is reasonably accurate. you should always set a date in the distant past, e.g. jan 2nd/1970.

Comment: i did a test and it seems the cookie is set but it's not inserted into the database. At first login it is inserted but after logout and relog the column `Cookie_Log` is updated to empty

Comment: Try `session_start();` again right after `session_destroy()`... actually, modify the line `header('location: index.php');` to `header('location: index.php?headers='.headers_sent());` if you are redirected to index.php?headers=true then we might know what could be happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a timing issue. PHP superglobals are set ONCE when the script first starts up, and then are never touched again by PHP for the life of the script.

In the case of $_COOKIE, any cookies you create/delete with setcookie() will NOT be removed or added to $_COOKIE until the NEXT http request. e.g. the `Cookie:` header has to round trip from the client, and PHP only creates $_COOKIE with what comes BACK from the user, not what you sent out.

You have

```
setcookie(... new cookie...);

... use new cookie immediately
```

since that's a new cookie, it doesn't exist in $_COOKIE, and therefore you're inserting/updating your table with an undefined/null value.

Answer (score 0):

That's just a small mistake on `if ($row = $stmtt->fetch())` you're using assignment operator, use `==` instead.

BTW event when `($row == $stmtt->fetch())`  won't never be equal to `true`, since `$row` is empty before conditionally checked.

it should be

```
$row=...
if($row == $stmtt->fetch()){

}
```